# Опишите что делает команда : systemctl enable docker

Tags: linux, systemd

в общем я примерно понимаю, что она делает, но внесите ясность, кто хорошо знаком с темой. что конкретно меняется от того будет введена эта команда или нет.

Comment: к программе docker данная команда не имеет вообще никакого отношения. что именно делает команда подробно описано в справке. см., например: `$ man systemctl`, секция «unit file commands», описание действия «enable name ...»

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[systemctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#enable%20UNIT%E2%80%A6) – команда для управления подсистемой инициализации [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)).

[Systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) занимается контролем работы [служб (units)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) в Linux.

`systemctl enable UNIT...` добавляет указанные службы в автозагрузку. Таким образом они будут запускаться при каждом старте системы. Команда создает символическую ссылку на юнит в специальной директории.

Comment: пожалуйста, распишите подробнее, что делает такая команда